# Python Discord.py - Detect if a message invokes any commands

Tags: python, discord.py

I would like to know if a message could invoke any command, without executing it.

I mean, I have a message, and I would like to know if the message triggers any commands. Is there anything I didn't notice about in the docs? Something like `ctx.command`, that tells me what command could the message execute, without running it.

This is to make a perm check and a DM to the user if the bot doesn't have send permissions. Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The easier way to do this is to actually write a [check](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/commands.html#checks) that sees if the caller can invoke commands, and raise a special error if they can't.  Then you can handle that error in `on_command_error`, including messaging the user a warning.  Something like:

```
WHITELIST_IDS = [123, 456]

class NotInWhiteList(commands.CheckFailure):
    pass

def in_whitelist(whitelist):
    async def inner_check(ctx):
        if ctx.author.id not in whitelist:
            raise NotInWhiteList("You're not on the whitelist!")
        return True
    return commands.check(inner_check)

@bot.event
async def on_command_error(ctx, error):
    if isinstance(error, NotInWhiteList):
        await ctx.author.send(error)

@bot.command()
@in_whitelist(WHITELIST_IDS)
async def test(ctx):
    await ctx.send("You do have permission")
```

To actually answer your question, you can get the invocation context directly with [`Bot.get_context`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/rewrite/ext/commands/api.html#discord.ext.commands.Bot.get_context).  You can then check `ctx.command` yourself.  (The computer I'm on at the moment doesn't have `discord.py` installed, so this may not work perfectly)

You can check if the context invokes a command using `ctx.valid`. If `True`, it means it invokes a command. Else it doesn't.

```
@bot.event
async def on_message(message):
    ctx = await bot.get_context(message)
    if ctx.valid:
        if ctx.command in restricted_commands and message.author.id not in WHITELIST_IDS:
            await message.author.send("You do not have permission")
        else:
            await bot.process_commands(message)
    else:
        pass # This doesn't invoke a command!
```

Comment: Worked as it should, just a quick note: To check if the message does invoke a command, use `ctx.valid` . If valid is `True` it means the message does invoke a command, else it doesn't.

Comment: @Aimarekin Yep.  If the context isn't valid, then `ctx.command` will be `None`, so we're kind of checking for that.